# Form checked out or locked for error

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, infopath, sharepoint-addin

We have a Travel expense system developed using SharePoint 3.0 for submitting and approving travel claims. It's an old system and recently we changed all the user login information.

For example:

User1: 
Old login ID is `domain\user1`

New login ID is `domain\12345`

The new user information were updated into the SharePoint user profile.
After the change, users are able to submit claims however when the claim is routed to any approver, he is not able to approve with below errors:

```
5/12/2016 4:13:03 PM |  Infopath FormEvents_OnSubmitRequest: InfoPath cannot submit the form.
An error occurred while the form was being submitted.

The form cannot be submitted to the following location: http://officeapps.domain.com/TnE/Expense Claim/166509-0000014.xml
The file "Expense Claim/166509-0000014.xml" is checked out or locked for editing by domain\d773106.

5/12/2016 4:13:04 PM |  Infopath FormEvents_OnSubmitRequest Stacktrace:    at Microsoft.Office.Interop.InfoPath.SemiTrust.DAVAdapter.Submit()
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.InfoPath.SemiTrust.DAVAdapterObjectWrapper.Submit()
   at ExpenseForm.FormCode._ProcessReviewViewLogic()
   at ExpenseForm.FormCode.FormEvents_OnSubmitRequest(DocReturnEvent e)
```

User `domain\d773106` is the approver who is trying to approve the claim. It seems the claim is locked by the approver himself.

Any idea what is causing the issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of your issue should be the ownership was not released by the InfoPath.

You may need to add the Fault Handling activity in your workflow to deal with the exception.

Please find the **solution in answers** within below mentioned link's discussion.

[User is shown message "is checked out for editing by" their domain\username - how to troubleshoot/resolve](http://www.networksteve.com/enterprise/topic.php/user_is_shown_message_%22is_checked_out_for_editing_by%22_their_doma/?TopicId=101396&Posts=1)

If it did not helps you than please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Link is now dead.